# configparser -- extra witespaces in SQL queries after import from ini

Tags: python, import, ini, configparser

I'm trying to make some queries with python configparser/cx_Oracle.

## Steps:

1. import number from an .txt file:
   Sample:
   TC-01:123456789
2. Import the relevant query from an .ini:

```
[Section]
base = select * from DB_NAME.TABLE where ID in ('{}')
```

Expected:

```
base = select * from DB_NAME.TABLE where ID in ('{}')
```

Reality:

```
base = select * from DB_NAME.TABLE DBNT where ID in ('{}
')
```

Of course the query doesn't work because of the extra whitespaces between the ''s.

Has anyone has any ideas how/why these extra whitespaces come from/?

```
    def query_getter(self):
        """
        Gets the relevant queries for the testcase from the resultCheckerQueries.ini
        :return: as described above.
        """
        query_list = []
        testcase = configparser.ConfigParser()
        testcase.read(self.ini_path)
        for key, value in testcase[self.testcase].items():
            print("CURRENT QUERY: ", value.format(self.ID))
            query_list.append(value.format(self.ID))
        print('For the test case {} the following queries are defined:'.format(self.testcase))
        for query in query_list:
            print(query)
        print('==========================')
        return query_list
```

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior: if I copy and paste your example config into a file and read it with a `configparser.ConfigParser` object, `cf.get('Section', 'base')` returns exactly `select * from DB_NAME.TABLE where ID in ('{}')` with no extraneous whitespace.

Comment: Of course you can't :( 
I just figured out -- after one and a half hours - that I import the wrong thing. 
I'm working from a list like this ['TC-01', '12345678911\n'].  I'm an idiot. 
But, thank you for the answare.

Comment: Any weird end-of-line issues going on? Ignoring your `query_getter` function, does the problem reproduce with the four lines necessary to parse the file and print out the value from the interactive Python prompt?

Comment: Don't forget to use bind variables instead of text substitution in your queries.  This is important for security and for scalability.  See the cx_Oracle user guide [Binding Multiple Values to a SQL WHERE IN Clause](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-multiple-values-to-a-sql-where-in-clause).